# Ubuntu 16.04 Server - Delayed Rebooting Issue

Tags: ubuntu, backup, reboot

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server that once rebooted rather immediately when I would issue this command:

```
sudo reboot
```

After this, I would typically be able to "log back in" in about 30 to 60 seconds.

Lately, however, when I reboot (and try to log back in 60 seconds later) I get this denial:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

It seems like the server is not shutting down right away. It eventually will reboot (10 minutes later or so), but during the interim I can ping it, but cannot log into it.

What kind of things could be holding it up? I'm accustom to Linux servers rebooting immediately; what can delay sudo reboot?

Comment: What does the serve do?

Comment: Might be worth dividing the problem in two-- delayed shutdown & delayed startup.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro : The server is a NFS share and it also mounts some windows file systems for scheduled rsync backups. However, none of the backups were in progress at the time of reboot mentioned.

Comment: @JeffSchaller : I agree, however it seems like the shutdown portion is the part getting delayed. Because, after issuing the reboot command, I immediately ping (recurring every second) and it takes a long time before the "shutdown portion" of the reboot occurs. The "startup portion" is normal.

Comment: Does the server *mount* NFS shares, or export/serve them?

Comment: @JeffSchaller : The server host a NFS share located on of its internal harddrives. [Proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com/en/proxmox-ve/comparison) uses this NFS share to backup virtual machines.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: It serves the NFS share and mounts the windows network shares.